# Modifying Nexus to add custom metadata

Tags: metadata, nexus

I need to make a modification to some projects I'm pushing into Nexus to add a handful of key-value pairs of metadata which allow for automation further downstream (think, things like should I send this file to a virus scanner, our New York office mirror, tape storage, etc).

It seems like there's a plugin to add custom metadata into the Nexus Pro UI. (The Pro version is unfortunately out of the question, any commercial software is).

I don't need any UI functionality from this as it's just for automation so I was wondering if there's a way I can, perhaps say, add some properties to a Maven pom.xml and push that into Nexus and have a server side script parse it from the filesystem. At a quick look it doesn't seem as though the pom.xml stored with a jar file I looked at is actually a Maven pom.xml but some JSON.

I'd like this to work for non-maven / Java files too ideally. Perhaps a top level descriptor file with a standard filename within the package? I'm reluctant to fork Nexus and the plugin documentation is sparse at best which seems to reflect the sparsity of the API. Anyway, I was wondering if anyone had any better suggestions... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the custom metadata plugin is part of the [professional edition of Nexus](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-browsing.html#custom-metadata-plugin), but there is nothing stopping you uploading the special file used by the plugin.

As explained in the following support question, the information is not stored in the module's POM file, instead it's an [N3 formatted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation3) file:

- [How can I add additional custom metadata to an artifact when it is deployed](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21474027-How-can-I-add-additional-custom-metadata-to-an-artifact-when-it-is-deployed-)

This file could then be easily downloaded and parsed.

Clearly you don't have to adopt Sonatype's convention, there's nothing stopping you from creating your own custom metadata file format and uploading it alongside the jar and POM file.